# How to "reconstruct lines" of data read from SerialPort using Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm just learning Rx and was trying to implement a "NMEA sentence reader" from a GPS device using SerialPort. The fact that it's GPS data is of lesser importance to the question, so let's just clarify that the NMEA format consists of lines, and a '$' sign represents the start of a new entry, so you get "sentences" that look similar to:

```
$[data for first line goes here]
$[data for second line goes here]
...
```

Hooking up the SerialPort's DataReceived event is pretty straightforward:

```
 var port = new SerialPort("COM3", 4800);

 var serialPortSource = Observable.FromEventPattern<
    SerialDataReceivedEventHandler,
    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>
    (
        handler => port.DataReceived += handler,
        handler => port.DataReceived -= handler
    ).Select(e => port.ReadExisting());
```

This gives an `IObservable<string>`, but obviously the strings returned here are not necessarily aligned as NMEA sentences. For example, for the above sample data, one could get a sequence like this:

```
$[data for first line g
oes here]\r\n$[data for
second line goes here]
```

How to properly turn this into a sequence of actual sentences? In the `IEnumerable` world, I would probably start from a sequence of `char`s and write an extension method similar to this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ToNmeaSentence(
    this IEnumerable<char> characters
)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var ch in characters)
    {
        if (ch == '$' && sb.Length > 0) 
        {
            yield return sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();
        }
        sb.Append(ch);
    }
}
```

Now I'm wondering if there is an idiomatic way for this kind of operation in Rx?

Comment: Nothing like Rx to obfuscate the simple.  Somebody somewhere has to maintain a buffer that keeps track of what was previously received, then append newly received data to it and implement the rule that says that a complete response was gathered so it can be processed.  That's all missing from your code.

Comment: @HansPassant haha, +1 :-). I guess that's kind of the point of this question: is there a simple way to do this in Rx (like the simple extension method with IEnumerable)?

Comment: That being said, this can be done easily in Rx. Enumerables and Observables are just inverses of each other. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: You just don't have the right skills to post `&&`.  Don't worry, you'll improve with time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's exactly the same code as Enumerables. You use `Subscribe` instead of fast enumeration, and you use `observer.OnNext` instead of `yield return`. Oh, and you have to use `Observable.Create`, because C# doesn't have language support for Observers like it does for Enumerables (yet. And that's not a failing of Rx).

Enumerables and Observables are exactly the same thing. One pushes, the other pulls. Creating them has a slightly different syntax. That's all.

```
public static IObservable<string> ToNmeaSentence(
    this IObservable<char> characters
)
{
    return Observable.Create<string>(observer => {

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        return characters.Subscribe(ch => {

            if (ch == '$' && sb.Length > 0)
            {
                observer.OnNext(sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();
            }
            sb.Append(ch);

        });

    });
}
```

I don't usually program on this low of a level, but Observables don't *complicate* it any more than Enumerables do. When people first learn Enumerables, it's hard to understand. When people first learn Observables, it's hard to understand. Both of them do the same thing, but one pushes and one pulls. There's 1-1 relationship between the two aside from that one distinction.

You would be wrong to think Rx is any more complicated than Enumerables and LINQ to Objects. It just appears that way when you're still learning it.

Comment: Very nice insight.  There's a tendency with Rx developers to try to always do it with existing operators when sometimes the simple solution is just as good.

Comment: `onNext` should be `OnNext`, and also there is no OnCompleted

Comment: @LeeCampbell it works for me. OnCompleted is not really needed in this case because it's an infinite sequence

Comment: Sorry about the `onNext` typo. Coming from JavaScript land over here. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. My current thinking is that you need an operator that takes a source sequence and breaks it into (consecutive) windows based on a predicate.

This operator could be useful.

```
public static IObservable<IObservable<T>> WindowByExclusive<T>(this IObservable<T> input, Func<T, bool> isWindowBoundary)
{
    return Observable.Create<IObservable<T>>(o=>
    {
        var source = input.Publish().RefCount();
        var left = source.Where(isWindowBoundary).Select(_=>Unit.Default).StartWith(Unit.Default);
        return left.GroupJoin(
                        source.Where(c=>!isWindowBoundary(c)),
                        x=>source.Where(isWindowBoundary),
                        x=>Observable.Empty<Unit>(),
                        (_,window)=>window)
                    .Subscribe(o);
    });
}
```

It effectively breaks a source sequence into slices based on a predicate.

You could use it by first chagning your list of strings into a sequence of `char`s. 
Then you can apply the `WindowBy` operator with a predicate of `c=='$'`.
This will give you two windows with the data you want.
Now you have the data seperated, you can then join the characters from each window into a string with `string.Join`.

Full LinqPad sample

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new List<string>(){@"$[data for first line g", "oes here]\r\n$[data for ", "second line goes here]"};

    data.ToObservable()
        .SelectMany(s=>s)
        .WindowByExclusive(c => c=='$')
        .SelectMany(window=>window.ToList().Select(l=>string.Join(string.Empty, l)))
        .Where(s=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        .Dump("WindowByExclusive");
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class ObEx
{
    public static IObservable<IObservable<T>> WindowByExclusive<T>(this IObservable<T> input, Func<T, bool> isWindowBoundary)
    {
        return Observable.Create<IObservable<T>>(o=>
        {
            var source = input.Publish().RefCount();
            var left = source.Where(isWindowBoundary).Select(_=>Unit.Default).StartWith(Unit.Default);
            return left.GroupJoin(
                            source.Where(c=>!isWindowBoundary(c)),
                            x=>source.Where(isWindowBoundary),
                            x=>Observable.Empty<Unit>(),
                            (_,window)=>window)
                        .Subscribe(o);
        });
    }
}
```

Ouput:

**WindowByExclusive**

```
[data for first line goes here]
[data for second line goes here]
```

Comment: Ok. You should stick to simple enough.