# Publishing decoded messages from a Stream while keeping encapsulation in Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm new to using Rx and I've been trying to re-write my MVC w/ Service Layer (*NOT ASP*!) to use this awesome new-fangled Rx. I have a class called `Remote` which encapsulates a `NetworkStream`. The `Remote` uses Rx to listen to bytes from the `NetworkStream` and once it works out it's received a full message worth of data, it decodes that data into an `IMessage`.

I get how I can read from the `Stream` continuously using Rx from inside the `Remote`, but how do I publish decoded `IMessage` from that stream to the outside world from the `Remote`? Am I supposed to use the classic evented style in C# and have the consumers of the events use `Observable.FromEvent`?

I only ask because I've read around that `IObservable` is not meant to be implemented anymore.

Comment: Welcome to the Rx revolution! (but we aren't that new, been around for +4years now)

The basic trick with Rx is to create sequences of data. Similar to how Shell junkies (DOS/BASH/Powershell) create Pipelines. So the idea would be to take your observable sequence from your NetworkStream and transform that data in your Remote and then expose the transformed sequence to the outside world.

I would love to give an example, but the options are endless, and potentially not very helpful. If you can give more detail on your problem space, a solution could be provided.

Comment: @LeeCampbell I think he's refering more to interfaces than implementations. :)

Comment: Could you break your questions up? Theres a question about interfaces, and a question about implementation regarding stream -> event processing. I think the stream -> event processing question would be better suited in a seperate question. :)

Comment: The main question I was asking was how to make Rx interface with the outside world - currently, I use an event to make the model (remote) notify the controller (Network Controller) that a message has been received, which then notifies a service. This uses C# style events. I discovered Rx and was interested in porting the c# style event into something that looked more like a stream so that messages could be source-ignorant (i.e you could fire a message from within the program and the program would not care about where it came from (net/program), just know it had an abstract actor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I supposed to use the classic evented style in C# and have the
>   consumers of the events use `Observable.FromEvent`?

If you're not positively forced to do so, ***do not make an API using C# style events***. The `IObservable<T>` is a powerful, generic, ***widely supported*** interface which allows us to treat events as first class citizens while easily managing subscriptions. Even if your consumer isn't using Rx, they'll be able to understand and use `IObservable<T>` more easily than using C# events. What they do with those events is up to them, but the `IObservable<T>` abstraction is clearer and simpler.

> I've read around that IObservable is not meant to be implemented anymore.

It reality, what we mean is that there's probably not reason to implement `IObservable<T>` on your own, because we have tools to create instances of that type for us.

We have `Observable.Create(...)` which allows us to create observables from scratch. We have different types of Subjects like `Subject<T>`, `BehaviorSubject<T>`, `ReplaySubject<T>`, etc, which can be used as proxies and allow us to multicast values to multiple consumers, and we have operators which allow us to transform/compose any `IObservable<T>` into another type or kind of `IObservable<T>`.

> but how do I publish decoded IMessage from that stream to the outside world from the `Remote`?

You expose an `IObservable<T>` on your class / interface.

```
public interface IRemote
{
  public IObservable<IMessage> Messages { get; }
}
```

You could implement this in any number of ways. First, you could make it so each subscription to `Messages` gets it's own subscription to your underlying logic...

```
public class Remote : IRemote
{
  private IObservable<IMessage> _messages = ...;

  public IObservable<IMessage> Message {
    get {
      return message;
    }
  }
}
```

Or you could make sure that there's only ever one subscription to the underlying logic...

```
public class Remote : IRemote
{
  private IObservable<IMessage> _messages = ...;

  private IObservable<IMessage> _refCountedMessages
    = this._messages
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();

  public IObservable<IMessage> Message {
    get {
      return this._refCountedMessages;
    }
  }
}
```

Or you could make the connection process extremely explicit in nature.

```
public interface IRemote
{
  public IObservable<IMessage> Messages { get; }

  public IDisposable Connect();
}

public class Remote : IRemote
{
  private IObservable<IMessage> _messages = ...;

  private IObservable<IMessage> _connectableMessages
    = this._messages
        .Publish();

  public IObservable<IMessage> Message {
    get {
      return this._connectableMessages;
    }
  }

  public IDisposable Connect()
  {
    return this._connectableMessages.Connect();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the next issue Dan will face is how to get the data from what is probably a raw network stream into a sequence of IMessages. That is going to be the fun part. I am guessing an tricky GroupJoin operator...?

Comment: Oh interesting. I misread those couple of words "I get how." In reality, these are two separate questions. Good catch. :)

Comment: A `Scan` operator that produces a Tuple<buffer, any new messages> followed by a where clause to filter to just the iterations that produce new messages can work.  Your scan operator just keeps adding the new data from the network stream to the buffer until it has enough to decode into one or more messages.

Comment: I thought the observable would be more of a "publish" style thing - so I could push the data. I guess you do that by adding the messages to a list?

Comment: @DanPantry - the IObservable interface lets subscribers listen to published messages but does not specify how you actually publish them.  Rx has a number of solutions to that.  One obvious solution is to just use a `Subject<IMessage>` as your `_messages` private field.  You only expose its `IObservable` interface to the public API but privately you will be able to push new messages into it.

Comment: I would avoid the usage of Subjects where possible. Brandon's Scan idea sounds brilliant.

Comment: After reading this I'm wondering why am I exposing messages as an enumerable? The idea is that a remote is basically a connection to a remote end and that I should only be reading the messages as they come in, and then ignoring them thereafter. The Remote (model) notifies it's observer (controller) it has a parsed message, and the controller takes that message and sends it upstream to a message service (service layer) which then should notify observers that a message was received to do X Y Z.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris "do not make an API using C# style events" -- Is this your opinion, or is this published guidance from Microsoft? I've never heard any proscriptions against using events for an API.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you problem is similar to this question [How to "reconstruct lines" of data read from SerialPort using Rx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784429/how-to-reconstruct-lines-of-data-read-from-serialport-using-rx)?

Instead of getting strings pushed at you that you then change into messages, you will get bytes. No problem, you can use the same WindowBy concept to slice up your sequence of bytes into windows that can then be translated/converted/mapped/whatever into your `IMessage`.

Building on Christopher Harris' answer. Here is an implementation of his proposed interfaces. The point here is to show that you can expose observable sequences that are just queries built on top of an underlying observable sequence. In this case the Messages sequence is just a query over the network sequence. With layering we get the level of abstraction that the consumer wants.

```
void Main()
{
    var networkStream = new NetworkStream();
    var remote = new Remote(networkStream);
    remote.GetMessages().Dump("remote.GetMessages()");
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class NetworkStream
{
    //Fake getting bytes off the wire or disk
    public IObservable<byte> GetNetworkStream()
    {
        var text = @"Line 1.
Hello line 2.
3rd and final line!";

        return Observable.Zip(
            UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text).ToObservable(),
            Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)),
            (character, time)=>character);
    }
}
public interface IMessage
{
    string Content {get;}
}
public class Message : IMessage
{
    public Message(string content)
    {
        Content = content;
    }
    public string Content {get; private set;}
}
public interface IRemote
{
    IObservable<IMessage> GetMessages();
}
public class Remote : IRemote
{
    private readonly NetworkStream _networkStream;
    private readonly byte[] _delimiter = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
    public Remote(NetworkStream networkStream)
    {
        _networkStream = networkStream;
    }
    public IObservable<IMessage> GetMessages()
    {
    return  _networkStream.GetNetworkStream()
                            .WindowByExclusive(b => _delimiter.Contains(b))
                            .SelectMany(window=>window.ToArray().Select(bytes=>UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)))
                            .Select(content=>new Message(content));
    }
    //TODO Add IDispose and clean up your NetworkStream
}

public static class ObservableEx
{
    public static IObservable<IObservable<T>> WindowByExclusive<T>(this IObservable<T> input, Func<T, bool> isWindowBoundary)
    {
        return Observable.Create<IObservable<T>>(o=>
        {
            var source = input.Publish().RefCount();
            var left = source.Where(isWindowBoundary).Select(_=>Unit.Default).StartWith(Unit.Default);
            return left.GroupJoin(
                            source.Where(c=>!isWindowBoundary(c)),
                            x=>source.Where(isWindowBoundary),
                            x=>Observable.Empty<Unit>(),
                            (_,window)=>window)
                        .Subscribe(o);
        });
    }
}
```